# Вырезать часть строки в php

Tags: php

Прошу прощение за простейший вопрос, но вошёл в ступор.
Как проще всего "вырезать" идентификатор видео в Youtube:

имеем:

```
$data = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrTXAX4Ux90";
```

нужно получить:

```
$video = "CrTXAX4Ux90";
```

Заранее извиняюсь, жара +30 голова не очень варит(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Два варианта:

```
$url = parse_url($data);
if(isset($url['query'])) {
    parse_str($url['query'], $query);

    echo $query['v'];
}
```

и в лоб:

```
$temp = explode("=", $data);

echo $temp[1];
```

ПыСы: У нас жара 40, но я привык :)

Comment: Спасибо милый человек!

Comment: explode тут нельзя юзать, предположим что кроме ID там содержатся еще какие-либо GET параметры. Тогда нам будет возвращена строка с параметрами. Так что лучше юзать только parse_str

Comment: @Shelkot все верно, но я на конкретном примере продкмонстрировал.